# Xamarin Forms ListView.Footer Margin not applied on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im working with Xamarin for the first time, and I dont have any clue why this appears:

I have a ListView inside a RefreshView (which is new in Xamarin.Forms 3.2) and I want to specify a Footer for this ListView. This footer needs some margin, but the top and right margin arent applied on iOS, regardless of the Version or the (virtual) device model.

```
<RefreshView>
   <ListView>
      <ViewCell>
         <local:Content_Card/>
      </ViewCell>
      <ListView.Footer>
         <Frame
            BorderColor="Green"
            Margin="10,10,10,10"
            CornerRadius="5">
            <Label
                Text="FooBar"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
         </Frame>
      </ListView.Footer>
   </ListView>
</RefreshView>
```

The code above produces the following:

[image]

How can I get the footer aligned with the "cards" above, and also for them to have some spacing between the second card and the footer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, it seems like an issue in Xamarin. Which version of XamarinForms and VisualStudio used , if needed I will submit in GitHub later .

Comment: I have submitted it as an issue , you also can follow it up [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8217) .

Comment: Thought of that, too.
I used the latest version of both of them, xamarin.forms in version 4.3.0.908675 and VS19 in version 16.3.6

Comment: Yeah , I also tested in the latest version . It works in Android , however not in iOS.

Comment: You will need platform specific margins. Common in Xamarin when making things look the same in both platforms